# How to loop through the columns in an R data frame and View/ Load data frame using the Row name in each iteration?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, factors

```
A <- c(4,13,1,3,8,15)
B <- c(15,4,1,11,5,7)
C <- c(4,4,3,1,5,8)
D <- c(12,7,8,9,3,2)
```

First Dataframes

```
df_01 <- data.frame(A,B)
df_02 <- data.frame(B,C)
df_03 <- data.frame(C,D)

Frames <- c("df_01", "df_02", "df_03", "df_04", "df_05")
Loop_num <- seq(1:5)
cat <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

Second Dataframe which contains details of other Dataframes "Frames"

```
df <- data.frame(Loop_num, Frames, cat)
df
```

Wish to loop through list and run call each data frame from list

```
    for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
      # Open / View Each dataframe from list (Help)
        # Open / View Each dataframe from list (Help)
  df[j,2]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your data.frames into a list of data.frames:

```r
df_list <- list(df_01, df_02, df_03)
```

Now you can iterate through each data.frame:

```
for (j in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  print(df_list[[j]])
}
```

Each `df_list[[j]]` returns the data.frame, therefore you can access the elements of a data.frame like

```
df_list[[1]][1,2]
```

which returns the element from row `1`, column `2` of your data.frame `df_ 01`.

If you want to access your list elements by name, you can create a named list:

```r
df_list <- list(df_01 = df_01, df_02 = df_02, df_03 = df_03)

# OR
df_list <- list(df_01, df_02, df_03)
names(df) <- df[1:3,"Frames"] # 1:3 because there are only 3 data.frames and df contains 5 names
```

In this case, you can iterate through your data.frames

```r
for (j in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  print(df_list[[df[j,1]]])
}
```